# Fried my motherboard/PSU?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I was experimenting with making a custom switch to start my computer, and I was using an LED toggle switch (I know now it's supposed to be a momentary) that needed 12v power for the light. Unfortunately, I think I touched either the Mobo's power/ground header to the 12v wire, and now the PSU won't start (either by reconnecting the original power switch and by bridging Green+Black with a paperclip).

Is there a way to fix it, or is everything just broken?

Comment: I'm not a hardware guy so just commenting. Two ideas come to mind: a fuse hidden like this article suggests: http://www.instructables.com/answers/WHERE-IS-THE-FUSE-INSIDE-MY-COMPUTERS-PSU/  or possibly a polyfuse that will reset after a while. That article links to this one, full of appropriate warnings (take heed): http://www.techrepublic.com/article/learn-to-re-fuse-a-power-supply/  and electricity can be nasty; there's the possibility something else went wrong. Even if you have a friend with a PSU tester, it might be best to replace it.

Comment: If the `green-black` jump failed (you only have 1 green and jumping to any black will work), when nothing else was connected to the PS and you had 120v power, then you either blew a fuse or fried the PS (they are cheap enough). Check for a fuse. If for some reason you took out more, you still may be in luck for a fair price. As a last resort, check [**badcaps.net**](http://www.badcaps.net/pages.php?vid=31). Old school board level repair.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in luck, the fuse may be burned and it's easy to replace (even with a  correct sized copper wire). If not, some of its components may have burned, in which case it's better to get a new one.

So just open it up and look for the fuse. 
Looks like this usually:

http://www.biline.ca/X-Box/psu_fuse_rep.jpg

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOHCK7bE6Bi3ctxWQPtXPfxlxTKU8K22G8qxv72eeSyrC7qbLqyw